# How to enforce microseconds with datetime()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'd like `date2` to output `2023-01-11 14:00:00.000000` to have a predictable format.

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime(2023, 1, 11, 14, 0, 0, 123456)
date2 = datetime(2023, 1, 11, 14, 0, 0)
print(date1)  # 2023-01-11 14:00:00.123456
print(date2)  # 2023-01-11 14:00:00
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Format it explicitly. Dates are binary values, they have no format and `print` doesn't support custom formats. Formats apply only when parsing strings into other types or formatting other types as strings for display or saving to text files

Comment: `date2.isoformat(" ", timespec="microseconds")`?